# First time here Cisco 3750 Switch

Tags: cisco, networking

1st time poster, I am trying to get two vlans talking to each other with out using a router. As I understand it the 3750 is layer 3 capable there for I would like to be able to get vlan 10 out to my router to the internet. What is going is I have 4 Hosts for Virtualization and it needs to get out the internet to get images down to the nodes. I am using Joyent Triton Datacenter so you know (This has to be on it's own segment because it uses pxe boot w/dhcp to configure Compute Nodes). I already have a dhcp server on Vlan1.

Is vlan tagging an option? If so can someone point to a good tutorial to help me learn it.

Vlan1 consist of fastEthernet0/1 Through fastEthernet0/9
Vlan10 consist of fastEthernet0/10 Through fastEthernet0/19(This needs to be able to talk to the internet).

Vlan1 ip is xxx.xxx.1.0
Vlan10 ip is xxx.xxx.10.0

Here is the Vlan setup

```
show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

C    xxx.xxx.10.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan10
C*   xxx.xxx.1.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan1
```

Vlan1 is the default network

The router I have is a Netgear Router not able to trunk, I know I know but it's the best I can do at the moment. and I need the Wifi.

If someone could help get this done I have configured it all the way to this point but now I am stuck here, I have been studyng interVLAN routing, I am just not sure how to finish this.

note: I know a bit about networking but I am not a Network Admin or Engineer

Thanks in Advance,

I have my configs and network pics[image: My Network]

Michael
P S I have my configs in a text file also if anyone wants to see them to help me resolve this. FYI Switch 2 is the one in question.

Thanks Again,

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the correct licensing, you would need to globally enable IP routing on the switch:

```
 ip routing
```

You can then create layer-3 interfaces. Add IP addresses to SVIs, and/or use the `no switchport` command on a physical interface to allow you to configure the interface as a router interface.

You can configure the interface to you router as a routed link.

The problem you are going to have is that the router will need to be told how to reach the networks on the other side of your layer-3 switch. If the router doesn't specifically know to send traffic for those networks to the layer-3 switch, it will send the traffic to its default route, probably the Internet.

Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through a dynamic routing protocol

Obviously, the first method is out for your router, so you will need to use one of the other two methods. Unfortunately, your consumer-grade router is off-topic here, so we cannot help you with its configuration.